# how to place image on top of qtmovie in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, qtkit

I am trying to make an OS X application in xcode 4.4 that can load a movie and place an image on top of this movie. The aim is to be able to resize/skew/distort the image with certain frames of the movies for measurement purposes.

I included the frameworks QTKit and Quarts/QuartsCore.
So far a dragged a QTMovie object in the window with a load button that can play a movie.
On top of that I place an IKImageView object with a transparent background. In the .m file i load an image into the IKImageView.

When building the app the image is shown nicely on top.So far so good.

When I load a movie suddenly the movie is on top of the image!
How can I keep the IKImageView on top? I've tried more object like a customview and button to place on top of the movie but while playing the movie it moves to the back automaticly!

Any ideas how to make this work? I've looked around for days for an answer to this but with no luck so far. I'm a bit new to xcode so I hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only way is to place a transparent window on top of the movie area:

this link solved it for me:

[Put a transparent NSWindow permanently on top of another NSWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128134/put-a-transparent-nswindow-permanently-on-top-of-another-nswindow)